# many to many table relationship dilemma

Tags: mysql, sql, database

by constructing a brigde table I would link many salesman and group together

I've made three table like below

```
salesman
========
uId

salesGroupLinked
================
uId
groupId

group
======
groupId
```

so it should be able to allow 1 salesman can have many groups and also many groups can own by 1 salesman. But now I thought of expand the relationship.

Says I want each salesman can have their performances score for each group. Where should I put the column? If it's at group table then it's obsoleted, because groupId is unique, so it may give a score to many salesman.

Comment: Do not call a table `group`, not even as a joke

Comment: @Strawberry lol why I never thought of that, pretty confusing uh..

Comment: It's not simply confusing. `group` is a reserved word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by thinking about the problem: What is the key of the performance score? It is settings of one salesman's group. So, the settings should be on the table where they are linked. It will be unique for each pair of `(salesman, group)`.

So the table would look like

```
salesGroupLinked
================
uId
groupId
PerformanceScore
```

Comment: one question, the uId and groupId of salesGroupLinked table is FK or PK? should be FK right?

Comment: @user3522444 sure, definitely FK. Consider also adding some artificial ID to the table as a PK, it is not 100% necessary, but can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

put the score in the link table.

The pk on that table should still be `uId` and `groupId`, but it should also have a column for the score.

EDITED to shopw DDL statements to Create table with Primary Key

```
create table salesGroupLinked
( uId integer not null, 
  groupId integer not null,
  performanceScore integer null,
  Constraint PK_salesGroupLinked Primary Key clustered (uId, groupId)
 )
```

The composite PK for this table itself guarantees that there can never be more than one row in this table with the same values for uId and groupId.

Comment: you mean which table? salesGroupLinked table contain PK? I thought they are FK?

Comment: Yes, the `salesGroupLinked` table, and yes each of these columns is a FK to one of the other tables, but the *pair* of them is a composite PRIMARY KEY for this table itself.  i.e., there can never be more than one row in this table with the same values for `uId` and `groupId`.