# phpmyadmin This table does not contain a unique column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've a bridge table, says it's table B which contains 2 columns and they are FK of 2 columns of table A and C. It make sense the FK can't be edit since they are references of other PK columns.

What if I've 3 column in table B? It seem like the entire table can't be edit..

I got this notification :

```
 This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.
```

Comment: `mysql` and `sql-server` ??

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason your table would occur from FKs? That is against the normalization rules and you should not really have all of your columns as FKs. The FKs are used to identify the other elements of the row that are not suppose to be FKs.

Comment: take a look Surgeon, I don't think there is no purpose even if within a table the columns are FKs : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312485/many-to-many-table-relationship-dilemma